# How to accommodate the boxes quantity in the available boxes

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I have boxes quantity define in the database against each hardware and boxes

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_Boxes (HWID  int, BoxId int, Quantity int);
INSERT temp_Boxes VALUES
--  (5, 1, 1),
--  (5, 1, 2),
    (5, 1, 3),    
    (5, 2, 6),    
--  (8, 1, 0),    
    (8, 2, 1);
```

Now I would have a parameter with `hardwareId` and the `quantity` that needs to be accommodate in that boxes let say:

```
set @hardwareId = 5;
set @quantity = 9; -- quantity could be any whole number
```

So I am confused here how about the way to achieve the following result with simple SQL queries which would return this result:

```
(5, 1, 3),    
(5, 2, 6)
```

what I have tried till now or could say the presudo-code in my mind is like to run the loop on the quantity and inside loop run the iteration on the boxes count

```
WHILE @quantity > 0 DO
   
    SELECT 
    *,
    @quantity quanvalbefore ,
        Case when qty >= @quantity Then @quantity ELSE @quantity := @quantity-qty END remain,
    @quantity quanvalAfter  
            FROM  temp_Boxes
            where HWID = @hardwareId
            ;
END WHILE;
```

any suggestion or solution to this problem would be helpful as I could not figure out that how i would go for remaining 3 item out of which 6 is already allocated

Comment: I think you might need to resort to brute force.

Comment: This sounds like a bin-packing problem which basically requires a brute force approach for an optimal solution.  Why wouldn't the answer by 1/2/6, for instance?

Comment: @asad What is the maximum number of rows per HWID? if it is very small, like 8-10 then brute force is possible/somewhat practical.

Comment: @SalmanA it could be of any number but yes by guess it wont pass 10

Answer (score 0):

You could create another temp table where you would store the planned subtractions. You could keep the `while` cycle that you have and have an insert into your new temp table from this temp table, store the hardware id into a variable at each iteration so that you will know which line you were at, subtract the value from quantity (if the result is negative, change it to null). After you inserted a copy of the record from your temp table into your new temp table, subtract the value from the temp table.

I did not write code for this one because I did not have time, so, if you need me to write some code for you, then please create some SQL fiddle with the test case and the table and share it with me.

Comment: Fiddle link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hjiGek2s1rztEe1odDCJ16/0  I wanted two (5, 2, 6)  and one (5, 1, 1) as given quantity is 13 in example

Comment: @Asad apparently MySQL does not allow dynamic limit. This is as far as I got: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/yEQSbwtscmuiUQbWLLzit/1 Basically you can solve this by creating another stored procedure and pass index as a parameter, unfortunately I do not have time to get into it further.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolved it and slightly modify the original schema also. Thanks guys for your helps.

[Solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7248cf7/1)